# when using $wpdb sudden connection rejection without changing anything. Access denied, with errors from repair tool

Tags: mysql, wpdb

WP version 5.5.3 - updated days ago php version 7.3.24 running locally on server Can not create a backup using duplicator Occours bothi inside WP admin pages, so internal connections and external through php requests

I am suddenly receiving the following error but have not made any changes to any file on the server, nor within wp itself -

WordPress database error: [Access denied for user 'database-name'@'localhost' (using password: YES)] .
THIGNS I HAVE DONE TO FIX - I have verified the wpconfig password and the db password match. I actually re-updated the db by copying the password listed in the wpconfig file and pasting it to the db. Searched a lot of solutions on here checked that the db is up and running by logging in using MYPHPADMIN

What am I missing and how do I get to the root of the issue that is causing this? No console errors are shown.

EDIT 1 - I have tried the WP repair tool and gotten the following errors:
wp_usermeta: 2 clients are using or haven't closed the table properly
wp_posts: 2 clients are using or haven't closed the table properly
wp_options: 2 clients are using or haven't closed the table properly
wp_postmeta: 2 clients are using or haven't closed the table properly
wp_term_taxonomy: 2 clients are using or haven't closed the table properly
wp_term_relationships: 2 clients are using or haven't closed the table properly

Comment: Have you actually tried logging in using the credentials you've given WordPress? Ideally from a shell on the WordPress server itself if possible. I'd also try re-granting permissions to the database to that user if you haven't already, and if that doesn't work make a new user with a simpler password (no special characters, just in case there's an escaping error in wp-config), grant that permissions and try and get that working. And once you've got that working try something more complex again.

Comment: Yes, the issue was that MYPHPADMIN created a temp user and then couldnt get rid of it. Had to wait 16 hours for that to expire or delete all views. Really stupid.